# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' while trying to declare a set of lists

Tags: python, list, set

I am trying to create a set of lists as follows:

```
# set of lists:
color_set_of_lists = {['red', 'green', 'blue'], ['white', 'yellow', 'gray'], ['purple', 'pink', 'lilac']}
print(color_set_of_lists)
print(type(color_set_of_lists))
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-af937f66571c> in <module>()
      1 # set of lists:
----> 2 color_set_of_lists = {['red', 'green', 'blue'], ['white', 'yellow', 'gray'], ['purple', 'pink', 'lilac']}
      3 print(color_set_of_lists)
      4 print(type(color_set_of_lists))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: sets cannot have any mutable objects as elements in them.

Comment: You can add _tuples_ to sets: Because they're immutable, they're hashable.

Comment: It's impossible to use lists as set keys, _because they can be changed in-place_, which would change their hash value, which would mean the index it was inserted with would no longer be correct.

Comment: Its not going to work. You can't put a list (or any mutable object) in a set. If it were allowed, its hash value would change whenever this list changed and future tests for the object in the set would fail. You can add tuples,  which are immutable, as long as the tuple's contents are also immutable.